# Vue convert functional component to Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I would like to migrate my Vue 2 functional component to Vue 3. I read their official [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/functional-components.html#components-created-by-functions) but don't understand it.

I have for example this component:

```js
module.exports = (name, path, ariaLabel) => `<template functional>
  <div
    :class="['main-${name}', props.width ? 'default-width' : undefined]"
  >
  <span  v-if="title">${title}</span>
  <span> hello </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test-${name}',
  props: {
    width: {
      type: [Number, String],
      default: null
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
  }
}
</script>
<style src="./style.css"/>
`
```

I got this far converting to Vue 3:

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

const MyComponent = (props, context) => {
    return h(`div${props.name}`, context.attrs, context.slots)
}

MyComponent.props = {
    width: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: null
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
}

import styles from './style.css';

export default MyComponent;
```

How do I properly import CSS? How would I add the nested span and the classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Styles

External CSS files can be imported into the file, and those styles will automatically be applied to the component:

```js
import './MyComponent.css'
```

#### `props.name`

You're using `props.name`, which isn't declared, so make sure to add it to `props`:

```js
MyComponent.props = {
  //...
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
}
```

#### [`h()` Arguments](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#h-arguments)

1. The 2nd argument of `h()` is an object of attributes, which includes `class`, so you would pass the multiple class names under the `class` key.
2. The 3rd argument of `h()` can be a string, slots, or an array of child elements, which are also created with `h()`, so you could nest the `<span>`s by passing them in an array.

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

const MyComponent = ({ name, width, title }) =>
  h(
    'div',

    // 1
    {
      class: `main-${name} ${width && 'default-width'}`
    },

    // 2
    [
      title && h('span', null, title), // conditional on `title`
      h('span', null, ' hello ')
    ]
  )
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/declaring-functional-components-in-vue-3-okdr3?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue.js)

#### JSX

Projects generated with Vue CLI also [support JSX](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#jsx) out of the box, which might be more straightforward given how close it is to the original HTML. Here's the equivalent of the `h()` calls above:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ name, width, title }) =>
  <div class={`main-${name} ${width && 'default-width'}`}>
    {title && <span>{title}</span>}
    <span> hello </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: @DouglasGaskell In Vue 3, the `context` argument of `render` includes `slots`, which contains the children nodes. You can pass that along in `createElement('div', null, context.slots)` to forward the children.

Comment: awesome solution! Do you know though how to type Functional Component in a non hacky way? I found FunctionalComponent type which is great but I can't find a recommended way to type Props or Attrs without using `as`

Comment: nvm found it! I can pass a type into the FunctionalComponent Generic. Gonna post another comment with the solution soon